How to prevent on xstate context update
I have a simple example of xstate context update.
There are other components that I don't want to be re-rendered.
Is it possible without useMemo()?
https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/n4jkrs (use console).
export const MyStateMachine = createMachine({
  context: { clickCount: 0 },
  on: {
    "button.click": {
      actions: assign(({ context }) => {
        console.log(context.clickCount);
        return {
          clickCount: context.clickCount + 1,
        };
      }),
    },
  },
});


export default function App() {
  const [myStateMachine, myStateMachineSend] = useMachine(MyStateMachine);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          myStateMachineSend({ type: "button.click" });
        }}
      >
        Click Me
      </button>
      <Component1 />
      <Component2 />
    </div>
  );
}

Thank you.
